# Can IIS or asp.net/mvc somehow achieve this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

There was some coding error recently, and the site was down for a couple of hours during working hour.

Our site is basically a publishing site, user can upload some excels and we grab information and generate some pdfs.

The final pdf location is something like

https://SomeUrl.url.com/Documents/ClientName/DocumentName.pdf

Documents is the controller and we map it to some action and ClientName and document name are the parameters.

What the client want is that even if the site is down (means they can't upload or modify anything), they want the above url to be still up.

Other than rewriting the whole logic, is there something we can do in IIS level?

I thought about url rewriting or url redirect, but don't really think it is possible.

Anyone got any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: By the site being "down" do you mean that it's disabled for an update, or the server has crashed? Anything that would take down the site would probably mess with IIS. You can do a URL re-write assuming IIS is still up though. I would generate the PDF and stash it on another service such as [AWS S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3_QSAuth.html)  which lets you have expirable access tokens. Then they just need a link to that file and the site can stay down.

Answer (score 1):

[URL Rewrite IIS Extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) won't be helpful as it's based on URL pattern. It doesn't care about whether the site is up or down.
You should consider setting up a load balancer instead. It's its job to decide which server to hit depending on server current load or if it's available or not.

Comment: A load balancer can determine if a site is down or not, our current load balancer moves the site from 1 server to another. However, it won't move the site to another site on the same server.

Comment: What kind of load balancer do you have? I know that LB like Netscaler can be configured to "ping" a page and base its decision on that page ping result. That way it doesn't matter if the sites are located on the same server.